# How to query an SQLite db in batches

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite

I am using C# with .NET 4.5. I am making a scraper which collects specific data. Each time a value is scraped, I need to make sure it hasn't already been added to the SQLite db.

To do this, I am making a call each time a value is scraped to query against the db to check if it contains the value, and if not, I make another call to insert the value into the db.

Since I am scraping multiple values per second, this gets to be very IO-intensive, with constant calls to the db.

My question is, is there any better way to do this? Perhaps I could queue the values scraped and then run a batch query at once? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I see three approaches:

1. Use `INSERT OR IGNORE`, which will reject an entry if it is already present (based on primary key and unique fields). Or plainly `INSERT` (or its equivalent (`INSERT or ABORT`) which will return `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`, a value you will have to catch and manage if you want to count failed insertions.
2. Accumulate, outside the database, the updates you want to make. When you have accumulated enough/all, start a transaction (`BEGIN;`), do your insertions (you can use `INSERT OR IGNORE` here as well), commit the transaction (`COMMIT;`)
3. You could pre-fetch a list of items you already have, depending, and check against that list, if your data model allows it.

Comment: #1 sounds very interesting...that would cut my current calls in half. I assume this throws an exception if the insert doesn't succeed, correct? For #2, would I be able to know the result of each attempted insert?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) says that on ignore, no error is returned. So no, there wouldn't be any exception or warning saying an item was ignored. As for #2, if you use `INSERT OR IGNORE`, same situation, no warning on success. There is however the default, `INSERT` (equivalent to `INSERT OR ABORT`) which, on conflict, will return `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`. You'd need to catch that return value and implement your own error/logging system.

Comment: However, if you use `INSERT` without a conflict resolution algorithm (i.e. `INSERT OR ABORT`) inside a transaction, a failed insert will stop that transaction and a rollback of all previous changes since the beginning of the transaction will occur. I don't think you want that.

Comment: Hm so then I'm back to square one unfortunately. If there was a way to tell whether or not Insert or Ignore did not succeed, then that would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Don't insert or ignore then, just insert. You'll get the warning. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

Comment: yes, i already had it set up that way. was trying to cut my calls down...thanks anyways